# How to sort a responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, navbar

I'd like to put my search bar above other buttons like this

[image: 2]

But, my responsive navbar looks like this (I use Bootstrap 4)

[image: 1]

How could I change their positions?

My HTML code:

```html
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Géneros
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Acción</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Aventura</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Comedia</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Familiar</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Terror</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Romance</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drama</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Musical</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fantasia</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           Películas
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estrenos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ranking</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Más vistas</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Series</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar películas" aria-label="Search">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </form>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Entrar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="#"> -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Registro</button>
          <!-- </a> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My CSS code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .navbar{
        position: fixed;
        background: #0c1a4d;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 50%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your code to the inbuilt code snippet tool provided by stackoverflow to create a minimum reproducible example, this will help people provide you with an answer to your issue

Comment: Then just move the HTML for the search bar and buttons to above the ul?

Comment: @Capagris Hi! I'm new here I don't know how to add it. I'm sorry, I'll improve my questions the next time.

Comment: @FluffyKitten It's the responsive side of my navbar. If I move it, as you said, it would ruin the rest of the navbar

Comment: Based on the code you gave us, that is all that’s needed... If you need something different then you need to include the code that shows the *actual* problem. We can’t help fix problems we don’t know about in code we can’t see! Please see how to create a [MRE] and [edit] you question to include all of the *relevant* code that shows the actual problem, so we can see exactly what is happening and how we can help.